# Java class inner generic bound obscures parent interface generic bound definition

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, generic-programming

I have the following class structure, where I have a compiler error on the definition of the `ProxyFactory`class:

Error:(32, 47) java: type argument com.company.Factory.ProxyUpdatable is not within bounds of type-variable T

The minute I replace the definition of `ProxyUpdatable` to simply hold an object and remove it's type parameter however, the code compiles fine.

Why does the type parameter of `ProxyUpdatable` have an effect on the bounds of it's factory implementation `ProxyFactory`? As far as I can tell, adding generic bounds to `ProxyUpdatable` doesn't change anything bout the interface it implements `Updatable<ProxyUpdatable>`

```
package com.company;

public abstract class Factory<T extends Factory.Updatable<T>> {

    public interface Updatable<T> {
        void copyFrom(T updated);
    }

    static class ConcreteUpdatable implements Updatable<ConcreteUpdatable> {
        @Override
        public void copyFrom(ConcreteUpdatable updated) {/* copyFrom implementation */}
    }

    static class ProxyUpdatable<T extends Updatable<T>> implements Updatable<ProxyUpdatable> {

        private final T implementation;

        ProxyUpdatable(T implementation) {
            this.implementation = implementation;
        }

        @Override
        public void copyFrom(ProxyUpdatable updated) {/* copyFrom implementation */}
    }

    static class ConcreteFactory extends Factory<ConcreteUpdatable> {
    }

    static class ProxyFactory extends Factory<ProxyUpdatable> {
    }
}
```

Comment: I *think* there's no relationship between the `T` in `ProxyUpdateable` and the type that `Factory` must take.  Haven't tested it though.  Try changing the type variable name and then take good look at the source code, something might pop out at you.

Comment: Chaning `ProxyUpdatable<T extends Updatable<T>>` to `ProxyUpdatable<P extends Updatable<P>>` does not fix the compiler error. So not sure why you think it obscures something.

Comment: @markspace the relationship is ProxyFactory will need to update any possible implementation of Updatable<T>. It does this by internally delegating to a more concrete implementation of Factory T, by matching on Updatable.getClass().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Stop using raw types!**

It seems like the act of using raw types creates this compiler error. `ProxyUpdatable` is generic, so add generic parameters when you want to use it.

To fix this, change the declaration of `ProxyUpdatable` to:

```
static class ProxyUpdatable<T extends Updatable<T>> implements Updatable<ProxyUpdatable<T>> {
```

Note that it now implements `Updatable<ProxyUpdatable<T>>`

And then you have to change the declaration of `ProxyFactory` as well. You can make it extend `Factory<ProxyUpdatable<ConcreteUpdatable>>` or make `ProxyFactory` generic as well:

```
static class ProxyFactory<T extends Updatable<T>> extends Factory<ProxyUpdatable<T>> {
```

Comment: This makes sense, although I didn't see it until you posted.  Now the type `T` in `ProxyUpdatable` is the same `T` as in its super classes.  Well spotted.

Comment: @Sweeper Unfortunately I need the raw type to hide the the inner type of the proxy. The proxy factory will need to create instances of ProxyUpdatable of all possible types of T by delegating to concrete implementations of T factories. 

So ProxyFactory will create ProxyUpdatable instances where Instances will be ConcreteUpdatableA, ConcreteUpdatableB and so on

Comment: @Tunji_D What about using a wildcard? Does that help? `ProxyFactory extends Factory<ProxyUpdatable<?>>`

Comment: @Tunji_D "Unfortunately I need a raw type to..." No, you don't. Raw types should *only* be used when interacting with pre-Java 5 code. Raw types break the type safety of your code, in that you can pass any types for parameters with generics (*not* just those involving the omitted type parameter), and you can treat any generic return value as any type (albeit with a warning). Wildcards are the right approach.

Comment: @Sweeper I read your first answer wrong, replacing the raw type worked! Thanks so much

Comment: @AndyTurner excellent point, I'll be sure to remember that. Thank you